# Base 64 and gzip order?

Tags: python-3.x, base64, gzip

I have a bytearray that I'm trying to compress - is it typically base 64 encode first and then gzip compress or vice versa, gzip compress and base64 encode the result?

Comment: What happened when you tried both ways? Did they both work? Why use base64 at all?

Comment: @mkrieger1 populating an elasticsearch binary data field which expects a base 64 encoded string

Comment: when you first base64 encode and then gzip it, the result is not base64 encoded anymore. So when you need base64 encoded data, you have to base64 encode after zipping.

Answer (score 1):

gzip compress, then base64. To reverse, un-base64, then gunzip.